# $f(x_1,y_1)>f(x_2,y_2)$ and $g(x_1,y_1)>g(x_2,y_2)$ $\implies$ $x_1>x_2$ and $y_1>y_2$: what other conditions are needed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

in order to make the derivation in the title, what other conditions are needed, besides:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} > 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} > 0$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} > 0$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} > 0$?

In single variable calculus, one only needs the monotonicity to make such derivations, but haven't seen anything analogous for multivariate functions.

thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. How is the question different now? $f$ and $g$ seem totally unrelated.

Comment: @Marktmeister I understand what you mean. In the case I am facing, f and g both have concrete forms. So supposedly one more condition involving one more function may provide nonredundant information.

Comment: So do you require the partial derivatives to be positive or not? Else, one could do something silly like $f(x,y) := x$ and $g(x,y) := y$...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your propierty holds for $f$. Then, the converse is also true: If $x_1\leq x_2$ or $y_1\leq y_2$ then $f(x_1,y_1)\leq f(x_2,y_2)$. So, for every couple $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ we have $f(x_1,y_1)\leq f(x_1,y_2)$ and $f(x_1,y_2)\leq f(x_2,y_2)$ (as $x_1\leq x_1$ and $y_2\leq y_2$).

We show that the inequalities above can't be strict: if  $f(x_1,y_1)<f(x_1,y_2)$ then $x_1<x_1$, which is a contradiction; if $f(x_1,y_2)<f(x_2,y_2)$ then $y_2<y_2$, which is also a contradiction. Then it must be $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_1,y_2)$ and $f(x_1,y_2)=f(x_2,y_2)$, hence $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$. As this is true for every couple $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ is constant. Then the only functions verifying your property are, vacuously, the constant ones.

Comment: Thank you. I gather that you mean with the conditions I originally allow, it's not possible to show that the results hold for all possible (x_1, y_1) and (x_2, y_2) in their domain. In this case, is there any way to 1, derive a weaker result (in terms of any types of inequalities between (x_1, y_1) and (x_2, y_2)) with the original conditions; or: 2, add extra conditions so as to arrive at the result? (I edited the original post and added a similar but different condition as a starter) I guess I am trying to learn any general methodology for this type of problems, potentially non-elementary.

Comment: PS, for those of you confused by the seeming disconnect between R.V.N.'s answer and my question: I have edited my Q after his/her answer was made.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your new hypothesis. Anyways, note that my proof is true whenever it's true that if $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\operatorname{Dom} f$, then $(x_1,y_2)\in\operatorname{Dom} f$ (you could do an analogous proof with $(x_2,y_1)\in\operatorname{Dom} f$). This is independente of $f$ being continuous, differentiable, or whatever. Then, the only restriction you could put to $f$ for that property holding, is restricting its domain so that if $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\operatorname{Dom} f$, then $(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1)\not\in\operatorname{Dom} f$.

Comment: This could be done by setting $\operatorname{Dom} f:=\{(t,\varphi(t))\in\mathbb{R}^2 : t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where $\varphi$ is any real function.